# How To Update A Destructured JavaScript Variable Based On Scopes/Closures?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, closures

The following code below is a *destructured* **count** variable and **increaseCount** updater function.

How can I **update** the value of the **count** variable anytime I execute the **increaseCount** function?

Is this even possible?

**Note**: I do not want the **count** variable to be a **Global** variable.

From the code below I tried using **Closures** to solve the problem. But **1** is still displayed even after the second **console.log**.

```
function getCount() {
    let _count = 1;

    const _updateCount = () => {
        _count = _count + 1;
    };

    return [_count, _updateCount];


}

const [count, updateCount] = getCount();


console.log(count); /* <===== Expect initial count to be 1 */

updateCount();

console.log(count); /* <===== After calling updateCount I Expect count to be 2 */
```

1. I Expect **count** to be **1** when the *first* **console.log** is called.
2. When **updateCount** is called I expect the **count** variable to be updated to **2**.
3. Therefore when the second **console.log** is called I expect **2** to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current code, it's not possible if you want to be able to call `getCount` more than once - you destructured `count`, a primitive on the top level. The only way to change it would be to reassign the outer variable inside `getCount`, which is a bad idea.

```js
let count;
function getCount() {
    count = 1;

    const _updateCount = () => {
        count = count + 1;
    };

    return _updateCount;
}

const updateCount = getCount();


console.log(count); /* <===== Expect initial count to be 1 */

updateCount();

console.log(count); /* <===== After calling updateCount I Expect count to be 2 */
```

An easy fix would be not to put a primitive in the first spot in the array, but instead use a function which returns the inside `_count`:

```js
function getCount() {
    let _count = 1;

    const _updateCount = () => {
        _count = _count + 1;
    };

    return [() => _count, _updateCount];


}

const [getInternalCount, updateCount] = getCount();


console.log(getInternalCount()); /* <===== Expect initial count to be 1 */

updateCount();

console.log(getInternalCount()); /* <===== After calling updateCount I Expect count to be 2 */
```

Comment: This works. But is there a way not to make `getInternalCount`, not a function. I tried to make `getInternalCount` a _**getter**_ but it's still returning 1 after the second console.log

Comment: No, it's not possible without making the first item of the returned array a function of some sort

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `_count` is different than the scope of `count` you are trying to `console.log`

To show the value of `_count` you have to access it with a function, like this:

```js
function getCount() {
  // This is visibile only to the function getCount
  let _count = 1;

  const _updateCount = () => {
    _count = _count + 1;
  };

  const _showCount = () => {
    console.log(_count);
  }

  return [_count, _updateCount, _showCount];
}

// Count here will be a different variable
const [count, updateCount, showCount] = getCount();


console.log(count); /* <===== Expect initial count to be 1 */

updateCount();
showCount(); // Will show ===> 2

updateCount();
showCount(); // Will show ===> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an obect with an implemented `toString` method and use this variable in an primitive expecting environment for getting the count.

```js
function getCount() {
    let _count = 1;
    const _updateCount = () => {
        _count = _count + 1;
    };
    return [{ toString: () => _count }, _updateCount];
}

const [count, updateCount] = getCount();
console.log(count + '');
updateCount();
console.log(count + '');
```